# having Problem with adding menu to an app

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to add some menus to my app. here is my code:

java code:

```
package com.example.excercise;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView my_text;
    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        my_text=findViewById(R.id.textView);

        my_text.setText(new Date().toString());

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Random random=new Random();
                my_text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256)));

            }
        });

        button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Toast.makeText(this, "MainActivity: OnResume()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


    }
}
```

main_menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:title="Item1"/>
<item android:title="Item2"/>
<item android:title="Item3"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:title="Search"

    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
<item android:title="Item4">
    <menu>
        <item android:title="SubItem1"
            android:onClick="itemClick"/>
        <item android:title="SubItem2"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

I'm getting this message in red in logcat :

> 2019-07-14 02:49:18.148 6160-6160/com.example.excercise
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.excercise, PID: 6160
>           android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler itemClick in class com.example.excercise.MainActivity
>               at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.(SupportMenuInflater.java:254)
>               at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:482)
>               at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:530)
>               at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:206)
>               at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:184)
>               at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:128)
>               at com.example.excercise.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:69)
>               at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:4055)
>               at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:378)
>               at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
>               at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2549)
>               at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1589)
>               at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1869)
>               at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:230)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
>            Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.excercise.MainActivity.itemClick [interface
>   android.view.MenuItem]
>               at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
>               at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1693)
>               at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.(SupportMenuInflater.java:250)
>               at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:482)
>
> ```
>         at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:530)
>
>         at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:206)
>
>         at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:184)
>
>         at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:128)
>
>         at com.example.excercise.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:69)
>
>         at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:4055) 
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:378)
>
>         at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
>
>         at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2549)
>
>         at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1589)
>
>         at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1869)
>
>         at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:230)
>
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
> ```

what is the problem and how should I fix it? I should add that in all java classes that red message refer me to, I get the "cannot resolve R symbol" error.

Answer (score 0):

In your main_menu.xml add an id to the **item** element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item android id="@+id/item1" 
   android:title="Item1"/>
<item android id="@+id/item2" 
   android:title="Item2"/>
<item android id="@+id/item3" 
   android:title="Item3"/>
```

In your MainActivity.java add **onOptionsItemSelected** method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//respond to menu item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.item1:
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on item 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
  case R.id.item2:
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on item 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
  default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Finally to solve the *cannot resolve R symbol error*...You have not imported the R class into your java file.There are two steps to do that

**Step One**

Click on the R symbol you should see a red bulb...click on that red bulb...you'd see a popup showing import class...Click on import

**Or Step Two**

Click on the R symbol...Then Press **Alt** + **Enter**

I hope this helps...